# How to get and use the data in EditText and present it in a TextView

Tags: android

I'm wondering how do I get information from an EditText to an TextView? Not the specific line of text transfered, but the data.

The user is to enter a number. Click a radiobutton which holds for eg. 45. And then click the Calculate button and get the data shown in a textview.

Comment: What do you mean with data? Since data is the representation of something with a sequence of bits, the string the EditText contains is actually data..

Comment: by data i mean the value the user enters in the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Get the text (if that is what you mean by data from `EditText`) from the `EditText`, parse the numerical value then do the operation. Something like this:

```
String data = myEditText.getText().toString();
if(data!=null && data.length() > 0)
      myTextView.setText(""+Integer.parseInt(data) + numberfromtheradiobutton);
```